# Firebase Cloud Firestore - Authentication error via REST API

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to request a token and use it to read/write data from Cloud Firestore database.

To request a token I'm sending a POST via Postman with the following synthax:

`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key={API_KEY}`

and add the following to the body:

`{"email":"{YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS}","password":"{PASSWORD}","returnSecureToken":true}`

So I get my API_KEY by going to Firebase console -> Settings -> Project Configuration.

Then, my POST to request the token is as follow: (don't worry, there is no sensitive data here, they were modified)

[image]

Then, I receive this answer:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "jGEL4WSI9wRPU11yx9k9ZpAUac73",
  "email": "jeferson.pehls@gmail.com",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI1OTc0MmQyNjlhY2IzNWZiNjU3YzBjNGRkMmM3YjcyYWEzMTRiNTAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZWxldHJvbmljYS1hYjZiMSIsImF1ZCI6ImVsZXRyb25pY2EtYWI2YjEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1ODA5NTIxOTMsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJqR0VMNFdTSTl3UlBVMTF5eDlrOVpwQVVhYzczIiwic3ViIjoiakdFTDRXU0k5d1JQVTExeXg5azlacEFVYWM3MyIsImlhdCI6MTU4MDk1MjE5MywiZXhwIjoxNTgwOTU1NzkzLCJlbWFpbCI6ImplZmVyc29uLnBlaGxzQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJqZWZlcnNvbi5wZWhsc0BnbWFpbC5jb20iXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9fQ.H0Mj3J7q_8L9IDAK2-zCZFaN1NP9tG6PKPpmEtjlNcSpT2zxXXPpHN-lxgVhyj_2EDxT1_ZikX2_l4EFBmy2ctYmYOxZF0Pm1UnFaLnXFRMFg7kFxkk6wLZlwI_cFp1TGmYZdgwJBhoude_ItmGlbGFSQGjwyO00DVyHq1nRIh-zl-NUXdMABLE_hbGYlXPYO6VlHLZ-ROXx4n-OnQ2bamNo4l0kp9YRV1z44jYR9ngbkW-eWgu4O7lRSlHgY0rBKF8lnPA__vKEgLyU-hheMwIFVdn7jVJkoKWkWm_-q6MVTCv9YKc0JNDlJm07QGBjss5xBbNWwlPfQ-MBejReoQ",
  "registered": true,
  "refreshToken": "AEu4IL2RMDFBsoQ5FEsN6rSznT2oElkKSxude28oFWspMHBAzY0J084TbIPfhTtOoKFePO3lnBFpExLraVVE2E2CW2JMSJQ7FFXlrExqULkYdG3n1OxHk8VU01GvBMwJdDTC6i48OOinouYRludjz0tA6xvmaOgfhmm9-NXj3SYU1AIkSXJi5ghYxRuiO4STwg_GpjvRP0Z-NdisYX01wHxmuETHu80VVA",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

[image]

Then, I will try to use that token that was received:

On Postman, I do a GET `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/eletronica-ab6b1/databases/(default)/documents/colA/docA.json`, where colA is the COLLECTION and docA is the DOCUMENT. The body of this request is selected as 'none'. Then I click on "Authorization" tab, choose TYPE "Bearer Token" and at the Token field I paste the token string received on the previous request. Then click to SEND. And receive this answer:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

What can be the reason of this error? What could be missing?

Could it be the rules? My current rules are these, I have not changed them at anytime, they are original values since I created the database.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST api calls won't let you access database with these rules. You should change **allow read, write: allow read, write: if true;** to make it available for any user.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true; //<--- Here
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: Making read, write true is a security vulnerability. Either you should use **if request.auth.uid != null;** to make only authenticated users to access the database (which includes using the token as you did here) or use firebase admin with nodejs backend with your current security rules. As it mentioned in firebase documentations, Firebase Admin SDK will bypass database security rules.

Comment: The things you said worked for me, thanks very much!

Comment: No worries. Better read the documentation first, most answers are already there.